# Metric Spaces are Normal

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is it true that for every metric space X: If $S$ and $T$ are closed subsets of $X$, there exists separated neighbourhoods $U$ and $V$ such that $S\subseteq U$ and $T\subseteq V$? By separated I mean that no point of $U$ is in the closure of $V$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Υes.

Take the continuous function $$f(x)=\frac{d(x,S)}{d(x,S)+d(x,T)}$$

Then $f$ is continuous and $0 \leq f \leq 1,\forall x \in X$

Also $f(x)=1$ for $x \in S$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x \in T$

Take $U=f^{-1}(-1,\frac{1}{3})$ and $V=f^{-1}(\frac{2}{3},2)$

And $V \supseteq S$ and $U \supseteq T$